# MPI ring_c not working on Singularity Container

Tags: mpi, singularity-container

I installed openmpi 4.1.2 and mpich 4.1.2 on a Ubuntu Bionic Singularity container.
They install fine, and I compile the ring_c from the test scripts and at first glance things work.
I tested that I can run mpiexec -np 2 ring_c from the host machine.
I can run mpiexec -np 2 ring_c from the Singularity container.
I cannot run mpiexec -np 2 singularity exec container.sif /path/to/container/ring_c.
It just sits at:
Process 0 sending 10 to 0, tag 201 (1 processes in ring)
Process 0 sending 10 to 0, tag 201 (1 processes in ring)

And it never progresses. I have also been able to replicate this on the container by issuing:
mpiexec ./ring_c

If I don't give it -np greater than 1 it just hangs.

If i do that outside of the container, it finishes just fine.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Has anyone had this problem?

**EDIT**

Interesting. The libraries do not match between the container and the system:

```
apple@adm01:~> ldd ring_c

        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000155555551000)
        libmpi.so.40 => /cm/shared/apps/openmpi4/gcc/4.1.2/lib/libmpi.so.40 (0x0000155554fd7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000155554db4000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00001555549bf000)
        libopen-rte.so.40 => /cm/shared/apps/openmpi4/gcc/4.1.2/lib/libopen-rte.so.40 (0x0000155554708000)
        libopen-pal.so.40 => /cm/shared/apps/openmpi4/gcc/4.1.2/lib/libopen-pal.so.40 (0x0000155554452000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000155554249000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000155554045000)
        libhwloc.so.15 => /cm/shared/apps/hwloc2/2.7.1/lib/libhwloc.so.15 (0x0000155553dec000)
        libudev.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libudev.so.1 (0x0000155553bb6000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x000015555384f000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000015555364b000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000155553434000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00001555531fa000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000155552eaf000)
        libevent_core-2.1.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libevent_core-2.1.so.6 (0x0000155552c77000)
        libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.6 (0x0000155552a74000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000155555329000)

apple@adm01:~> singularity exec /home/apple/singularity-mpi-simple/image-build/bionic-mpich-ring_c.sif ldd /home/apple/singularity-mpi-simple/openmpi-4.1.2-examples-ring_c/ring_c
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x0000155555551000)
        libmpi.so.12 => /usr/local/lib/libmpi.so.12 (0x0000155552801000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000155552437000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x000015555212e000)
        libatomic.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatomic.so.1 (0x0000155551f26000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000155551d09000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000155551b05000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00001555518fd000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000015555532e000)
```

Why would those need to match? I thought the whole idea of a container is to have your own environment.

**The Solution:**
The openmpi in the container was compiled with mpich.  When I was executing mpiexec outside the container, I did not have the mpich module loaded.

Comment: make sure you are not mixing MPI libraries inside vs outside the container. `ldd ring_c` on the host should use the same MPI libraries as reported by `singularity exec container.sif ldd ring_c`

Comment: Why would those need to match? I thought the whole idea of a container is to have your own environment.  See EDIT above.

Comment: `mpirun` **must** match `libmpi.so`. the logs suggest you are using Open MPI `mpirun` on the host, but MPICH (or an older Open MPI) inside the container.

Comment: YES! That was it. I did compile openmpi with mpich in the container, but I was not loading the mpich module when I was executing mpiexec from outside the container. I was only loading the openmpi module in our system. Once I loaded mpich AND openmpi modules it worked. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The Solution: The openmpi in the container was compiled with mpich. When I was executing mpiexec outside the container, I did not have the mpich module loaded.